# How to avoid callback hell in nodejs for sequelize

Tags: node.js, callback, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize and ending up in callback hell:

```
db.Role.findAll().success(function(roles) {
            db.User.findAll({where: {permission: 'coach'}}).success(function(coaches) {
                res.render('users/edit_profile', {successFlash: successFlash, user: user, roles: roles, coaches: coaches});
            }).error(function(errors) {
                console.log("Error", errors);
                res.render('dashboard', {successFlash: successFlash, errors: errors});
            });
        }).error(function(errors) {
            console.log("Error", errors);
            res.render('dashboard', {successFlash: successFlash, errors: errors});
        });
```

I want to avoid callback hell and make the code more reusable. Is there a way to do this without using async, promises etc?

Suppose I write something like this..

```
get_user: function(req, res) {
    var users = null;
    users = func.get_users();
    res.render('users/get_users', {users: users});
}

get_users: function() {
        db.User.findAll().success(function(users){
            return users;
        }).error(function(err){
            return null;
        });
    }
```

The problem with this approach is that, `get_user` renders the page first and then the callback from `get_users` is executed, giving me users as always null.

Please help me in this regard!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Callback hell? Where? I'm pretty sure callback hell is typically refering to where you have callback inside of callback inside of callback(...etc). You have promise style callbacks, and that's probably as good as you'll get. If you don't like callbacks, I wouldn't recommend a framework which involves heavy use of them.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My concern is that, I want to make the code more reusable. Using the above first approach, if I were to write another function in a controller, I land up writing all the queries again (probably, sequence would have differed). I want to put all the queries in a separate controller, inside different functions, and then call only the functions in some other controller. I hope, you got my point. :)

Answer (score 4):

Sequelize 2.0 ships with native promises, so you don't need to require a promise lib manually in your code. With 2.0 your snippet can be written as:

```
db.Role.findAll().bind({}).then(function(roles) {
  this.roles = roles;

  return db.User.findAll({where: {permission: 'coach'}});
}).then(function(coaches) {
  res.render('users/edit_profile', {successFlash: successFlash, user: user, roles: this.roles, coaches: coaches});
}).catch(function(errors) {
  console.log("Error", errors);
  res.render('dashboard', {successFlash: successFlash, errors: errors});
});
```

You only need a single `catch` block, because any error is propagated to the top of the chain when you `return` a promise.

The `bind({})` part makes an empty object available inside all functions in your promise chain so you can pass context along in that way. If could also do `bind(this)`, if you want to be able to access something from the outer context, without having to do the idiomatic `var self = this`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  get_user: function(req, res) {
    var users = null;
    func.get_users(function(result){
      if (result==null) //handle error
      res.render('users/get_users', {users: users});
   });
}

get_users: function(callback) {
        db.User.findAll().success(function(users){
            callback(users);
        }).error(function(err){
            callback(null);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This works! From the first code snippet which I have posted, suppose I want to fetch all roles first, and then users, how can I refactor the code?